# Включение визуализации win10

Tags: windows-10, виртуальная-машина, bios, визуализация

Для виртуальной машины потребовалось включить визуализацию,
не могу найти её включение в BIOSе. Везде читал оно там, но такая настройка отсутствует.
ОС: `Windows 10`.
Материнская плата:
`Gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2 R2`.
BIOS:
 `1 x 32 Мбит ПЗУ
Лицензионный BIOS компании AWARD
Поддержка спецификаций PnP 1.0a, DMI 2.0, SM BIOS 2.4, ACPI 1.0b`.
Процессор: `amd fx-4300`.

Comment: Ну как я понимаю вам нужна виРТуализация. Для amd она будет называться  amd-v. Ищите её в настройках. (на стареньком ноуте с amd a6 так пункт и назывался, сменил disabled на enabled и было счастье)

Comment: @Ljil, уточните, пожалуйста, в каких настройках?

Comment: в биосе ищите, вероятнее в advanced (если есть)